# Laravel HasManyThrough Relation with Where Condition on related table

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-relations

I want to get count of **Verified Doctors**  of a city based on hospital (where doctor works). I have created hasManythrough relation in City modal and when I'm using this relationship in **blade file** it gives all doctors (verified and unverified). I only want to get verified doctors. Here is my database structure:

**Database**

**doctors  (columns)**    ---id--name---is_verified--

**hospitals columns)**   ---id--city_id---name---

**doctor_hospitals (columns)**   --id--hospital_id---doctor_id

**Relation in City Modal**

```
    public function cityDoctors()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\DoctorHospital',
            'App\Hospital',
            'city_id',
            'hospital_id'
        );
    }
```

**In Controller**

```
 $cities=City::with('cityDoctors')->whereHas('cityDoctors')->get();
```

**In blade file** I use

```
   @foreach($cities as $city)
     <li><a href="{{route('typeSearch',['type' => 'city', 'id' => $city->id])}}">
        <strong>{{$city->cityDoctors->count()}}</strong>{{$city->name}}</a>
     </li>
   @endforeach
```

It show count of All doctors(verified and unverified).
**How to get only verified doctors of city?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's like many to many relation more than has many throw.

Anyway, you can do it using `whereHas` inside the eager loading statement (with):

```
  $cities = City::with(['cityDoctors' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('doctor', function ($query) {
                $query->where('is_verified', true);
            });
        }])->has('cityDoctors')->get();
```

Make sure of the relation name between CityDoctor and Doctor models

Comment: Thank you, it solves my problem, I was trying same thing except  **->has('cityDoctors')**.